# Dealing with files with spaces inside a FOR loop from files passed in command line in bash is failing

Tags: command-line, bash, shell-script, command-line-arguments

I am creating a script that will crop movies and have the following syntax:

```
 ./crop *.mov 0,0,100,100
```

or

```
./crop oneMovie.mov 0,0,100,100
```

So, the first parameter can be a wildcard pattern or one specific file.

I know that `$2` is equal to `0,0,100,100`, that are the crop parameters.

So, `$1` will be the passed files.

Now I need to create a loop to process these files.

Here are some variables used

```
fileEnd="-CROPPED.mov"
outputFile="$fileName$fileEnd"
```

So, I have a loop like

```
for f in $1
  // crop video
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter:v "crop=$w:$h:$x:$y" "$outputFile"
done
```

This fails for me if the file has spaces in its name.

I think one of the problems is that for a file with spaces `$2` will not be the argument (see script below).

calling the script `crop "*.mov" x,y,w,h` works but I would like to make it work without this "hacking" because I know I will forget that when I call the script.

The references to both `$f` and `$outputFile` are in quotes. Shouldn't it work?

This is the complete script

```
#!/bin/bash

# syntax crop *.mov x,y,w,h
# or
# crop oneFile.mov x,y,w,h


fileEnd="-CROPPED.mov"    

x=0
y=0
w=0
h=0

# get the crop values
if [ $# -eq 2 ]
then
  argumentCrop=$2
  IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$argumentCrop"
  x="${array[0]}"
  y="${array[1]}"
  w="${array[2]}"
  h="${array[3]}"
fi

for f in $1
do

  filename="${f%%.*}"

  outputFile="$filename$fileEnd"

  ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter:v "crop=$w:$h:$x:$y" "$outputFile"

done
```

Comment: call it as `./crop "*.mov" 0,0,100,100`

Comment: or change to `for f in "$1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you alter your invocation:

```bsh
./crop 0,0,100,100 *.mov
```

Then, in your script, you'll do:

```bsh
IFS=, read -r x y w h <<<"$1"
shift

for f in "$@"; do 
    outputFile=${f%.mov}-CROPPED.mov
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter:v "crop=$w:$h:$x:$y" "$outputFile"
done
```

The problem you're having is that the shell will expand `*.mov` **before** launching your script, so `$2` is *not guaranteed* to be the crop geometry, unless there's only one .mov file. `$1` is not a list of files, it is a single file.

---

Another approach would be pass the crop geometry as options:

```
./crop -x 0 -y 0 -x 100 -y 100 *.mov
```

then

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

x=0 y=0 w=150 h=75   # provide some default values

while getopts :Hw:h:x:y: opt; do
    case $opt in
        w) w=$OPTARG ;;
        h) h=$OPTARG ;;
        x) x=$OPTARG ;;
        y) y=$OPTARG ;;
        ?) echo "usage: $0 -w w -h h -x x -y y file.mov ..."; exit ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

for f in "$@"; do 
    outputFile=${f%.mov}-CROPPED.mov
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter:v "crop=$w:$h:$x:$y" "$outputFile"
done
```

Comment: BRILLIANT but I am trying to understand the shift on your first solution, that pleases me more than the second, even the second being 1000 light years ahead. The idea of having to type -h -w -x -y, makes my brain hurt. Anyway, isn't the shift shifting the parameters to the left? I do not understand what the shift does there... we have, for example, `crop x,y,w,h *mov`, you shift to the left you end with `x,y,w,h *mov`... *mov is still there... or I do not understand what shift does. Sorry, I am not very good in Bash.

Comment: @SpaceDog In the first solution, it parses the coordinates out of the first argument (with `IFS=, read`), then uses `shift` to remove that argument. With it gone, *all* remaining arguments are filenames to process, so `"$@"` (which gets all of the arguments) will expand to the list of filenames (and the double-quotes around it prevent confusion from spaces in filenames).

Comment: you say, then uses shift to remove that argument... what argument? To be just with the file name it has to remove `x,y,w,h`, or to be more specific, 4 variables. I see that it is doing this but I always thought shift would shift ONE variable left. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @SpaceDog `shift` has no effect on variables, only on the argument (aka parameter) list. Before the `shift`, the argument list would be something like "0,0,100,100" "movie 1.mov" "movie 2.mov" "movie 3.mov" etc (so `$1` is "0,0,100,100", `$2` is "movie 1.mov", etc). After the `shift`, the argument list would be just "movie 1.mov" "movie 2.mov" "movie 3.mov" etc.

Comment: ahhh, I got confused. I thought it would consider x,y,w,h as four arguments. When I said variables I was really saying arguments...  ... THANKS for the amazing explanation. +1 on everything.